# Tensorflow Object Detection API run eval.py,somewhere wrong

Tags: api, object, tensorflow, detection

when I finish the train.I want to python eval.py to look the precision,but when restoring from the model.ckpt,the The program is stuck.It's a bug?thank u

Answer (score 0):

give some further explanation of the error. When it stuck before it even start and what command do you use to run the eval.py

Answer (score 0):

open the tensorboard to see if there is any results and check the output dir